# ActionBarCompat - App icon action (click) not working on 4.0 devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have this problem with the [Android ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) project: On emulators with Android 4.0 the click on the app icon doesn't cause any `onOptionsItemSelected` event, whereas it works on all other OS versions.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you seeing any touch feedback from the app icon? (Does it glow when you press it?)

Since many activities do not use the action bar home button, in apps that target API 14+ running on Android 4.0 it is disabled by default. (This is so that users don't try pressing it, see it glow, and wonder why nothing happened.) Apps that want to use this should call [`ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled%28boolean%29).

We should probably revise the ActionBarCompat sample to surface this more clearly. One simple way to get you up and running would be to modify ActionBarHelperICS.java and add the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

In an app where you want more control over turning this on and off you would want to make further changes.

Comment: Just to note, this [is mentioned in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home), it's just easy to miss since it's a "Note".

Comment: It is not working for me. Adding this code I get error in Eclipse.  Multiple markers at this line
 - Call requires API level 14 (current min is 4): 
  android.app.ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled     fixed by adding supress new api

Comment: What if `minSdkVersion` must be 8?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. This code did the trick for me:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Some extra info: `minSdkVersion="7" targetSdkVersion="18"`. This is the `LAUNCHER` activity of my project, so it has no parent activity. Using `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in other activities worked just fine.

Comment: this should be accepted answer - it was the only thing that helped me