# can not click action bar app icon Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make the action bar app icon (top left image) clickable but it just doesn't work, I've already searched for some answers but nothing works. I've already tried to `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` and I can see the icon, but i still can't click on it. I know I can handle the event in the method `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` but the event will never get triggered with my situation. I also don't get why I have to use `getSupportActionBar();` instead of `getActionBar()`...the second one is always null. The minimum sdk is 16 and the maximum is 22. I read this answer -> [ActionBarCompat - App icon action (click) not working on 4.0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028197/actionbarcompat-app-icon-action-click-not-working-on-4-0-devices) but I don't know how to get in the ActionBarHelperICS.java class or if it apply to my case.

Comment: >but the event will never get triggered with my situation

what's special about your situation?

Comment: I can see the icon, but i still can't click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really posted any code. But there may be 2 problems.
You have to specify which is the parent activity in your manifest file.

Under the activity's tag in manifest, you'll have to specify which activity your home button will point to. Something like this:

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.MainActivity"
```

Or `Override` your onOptionsItemSelected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
//add what you want to do here...
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!....I added your code to the manifest and now I can see a little arrow to the left of my app icon. Now I can click on it and it also triggers the event. Problem solved, thnx Louis. =D